# Create readonly calendar event with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We'd like to use Microsoft Graph API to create calendar events in order to sync the calendar events of our own application with the ones in Outlook. However, in our application, we have time periods that are closed for altering. So, the events become read-only on our side. Now we need Outlook to behave accordingly. Is there a way to create a (or alter an existing event to a) read-only calendar event (prevent the user from changing the time frame or deleting an event)?

It is not sufficient for us to only listen to changes made in Outlook because it's forbidden on our side to delete an event that's already "closed" and without deleting it in our application, there would be an inconsistency in the data.

Comment: I am wondering if you find a way to achieve this. I would like to create an outlook event that is locked or unchangeable at all meaning that nothing can be changed on the Outlook side. The event should be able to be changed only through the API.

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be no way to achieve this, as of now.
I've settled with providing an ICS file for our customers via an API endpoint on our side.
Because ICS-events can get deleted or altered by the user, I'm adding a request-guid to our event-id resulting in the ICS-Event-ID. This doesn't prevent a user from deleting the event, but at least the event will be back again after reloading the calendar